# Finding the average of top 10 smallest values in Google Sheets

Tags: google-sheets

I'm looking for a formula to find the average of the top 10 smallest values within a dataset. It works in Excel but not in Google Sheets.

E.g. (that works in Excel):

[image]

```
=AVERAGE(SMALL(D2:BD2,{1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10}))
```

Answer (score 8):

In Google Sheets, you need to wrap `small` in [`arrayformula`](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/3093275?hl=en) so it produces an array:

```
=average(arrayformula(small(D2:BD2, {1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10})))
```

There is an alternative solution, which is shorter and scales better if  you will need 100 smallest instead of 10 smallest numbers:

```
=average(array_constrain(sort(D2:BD2), 10, 10))
```

Here, `sort` sorts the array in the increasing order. The [`array_constrain`](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/3267036?hl=en) limits the output to at most 10 rows and 10 columns, which in practice means 10 smallest elements, regardless of whether your data was in a row or in a column.

Comment: Perfect, the first option works the best for what I am after. Thank you.